# Keep eliminating data points until good correlation coefficient is obtained

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I have been trying to find out a way in order to eliminate outliers from a dataset. The outliers are removed the following way: Any value which results into a 10% reduction in R2 value needs to be removed. When 4.2 in A-data set got replaced with 1.3 (in B-dataset), it changed the R2 >10% and thus was eliminated in the C-dataset.

However, when 0.7 in A was replaced with 0.9, it would not change the correlation coefficient by 10% and thus was not removed from C-dataset.

An image is attached herewith.

[image: Eliminating outliers inorder to improve the correlation]

In the image, -plot A has R2 of 1.0
              -plot B has R2 of 0.8294 (1.3 is the outlier since it causes >10% lowering of R2 values)
              -plot C has R2 of 1.0 (on removing 1.3 from the dataset)

How do I go about this issue. I need to use python to get to the solution. Out of the 10 data points a maximum of only 3 data points can be removed inorder to improve the correlation.

I apologize if this question was asked before. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the question. I am an excel guy and used excel to get to it. However, it is extremely difficult to get to it. I started learning Python from past 2 weeks and now this question has come up where I need help. Any guidance to which place to look into will help out heavily.

Comment: OK. What have tried so far in Python? :-)

Comment: I apologize, since I have been learning python from past couple weeks, I am clueless which direction to go. If I know what to look into I will look into it. I deeply apologize, I asked a question without working on it much.

Comment: Any direction to look into the issue will be great...I know I need to work on the issue. Direction needed as to which path to follow for the solution.

Comment: I would start with any NumPy tutorial, e.g. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-numpy-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for giving the hint. I will look into this norok2 :) Thanks for showing a path.

Comment: First question should be whether or not this is the correct thing to be doing in the first place. Throwing away data points because they seem inconvenient is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want **robust linear regression**, ignoring the outliers. Such a thing is already implemented in [sklearn module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.HuberRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.HuberRegressor) but since it's not among the tags, here is a plain SciPy solution.

The idea is to minimize the sum of absolute values of deviations (L1 loss function) instead of the sum of squares. (Compare to: median vs mean.)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0.7, 7, 10)
y = 0.8*x + 1.2
y[5] = 2.5      # outlier 

l1_loss = lambda c: np.sum(np.abs(c[0]*x + c[1] - y)) 
c = minimize(l1_loss, (0, 0)).x

plt.plot(x, y, 'b*')
plt.plot(x, c[0]*x+c[1], 'r')
plt.show()
good = np.abs(c[0]*x + c[1] - y) < 0.1     # arbitrary threshold to separate good from bad
print('good data: x = {}, y = {}'.format(x[good], y[good]))
```

Output: "good data: `x = [0.7 1.4 2.1 2.8 3.5 4.9 5.6 6.3 7. ]`, `y = [1.76 2.32 2.88 3.44 4.   5.12 5.68 6.24 6.8 ]`".

[image: regression]

The line is not perturbed by the outlier at all.

You may want to replace `good = np.abs(c[0]*x + c[1] - y) < 0.1` with an iterative approach, where the data point with the largest value of deviation, i.e.,

```
outlier_idx = np.argmax(np.abs(c[0]*x + c[1] - y))
```

is identified and removed from x and y arrays ([`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)), then the process repeated until the correlation is good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is this automatic? Say I have 10000s of such sets of data from which I have freedom to remove 3/10 data points inorder to make the fit better. However, thanks for this robust linear regression method. I just now tagged sklearn too. Thanks for the guidance. No words to thank! I will try out this solution soon and then update.

Comment: Hi All in addition to the previous question I have following queries too: I am importing data from excel to python using pandas: Code is as follows: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel("S:/Data/Excel.xlsx")
df.head()

pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Test Event","Step" ])

#I have four columns
#Test Event, Step, Days,Temperature

"How do I transfer the columns 'Days' and 'Temperature' to numpy
 arrays so that I can find out R2 and slope using scipy and plot data in matplotlib?"

Days=x-axis
Temperature=y-axis

Comment: Hello, can you please guide me towards some link how to get the same output in in sklearn?